# Can I fix the undefined index error by changing the website address?

Tags: php

I want to access the website. but I receive error message 'Notice: Undefined index:...' .
Is there a way to access by changing the website address?
Is this possible by adding something like'?id=100' to the original website address?
(like http://~~~~/~~/~~/~~.php?id=100)

Comment: Hey there, please post a small reproducible example of your code, it'll help put your question in context - right now it is a bit difficult to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you don't have an access to this site's code.

This notice can be caused lots of ways as described in this answer by Rizier123: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/3925125

The only way how you would be able to "fix" this undefined index would be if it was direct access to $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE global variables.

You can try your luck by using these with the missing index's name:

- appending GET parameter to URL (e.g. ?id=1)
- sending POST request (use e.g. Postman)
- creating COOKIE (use e.g. EditThisCookie plugin on Chrome)

Comment: I use post request. so i can solve undefined index error. but how to solve problem about 

{"RETURN_V":106} I send post request but i receive 

{"RETURN_V":106}

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your code first, but I assume that your problem is `"Your view cannot read an index of array"`. It means, you expect to get data and want to show it on your view, but unfortunately, the data you wanted to get not found, and you need to make the condition.

Here is in my Laravel Code.

For instance my data in table user
`name: someone, age: 21`

```php
$data = User::where('name','someone')->first()
if ($data)
    return "YOUR VIEW"
return "Data not found";
```

The condition is, I redirect to my view if only the data was found.

Comment: Can't I fix this by adding an attribute (id='') to your website?